# Bootstrap button is non-clickable on a mobile view

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have this problem, my bootstrap button becomes non-clickable as I reduce the screen size of my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) to a mobile view. This problem only occurs when testing the script on a live server. On my localhost, there are no issues with the button.

This is  the code:

```
<?php
 $sql2 = "SELECT  i.*, m.*, c.*, i.id AS id_count FROM offers i
                JOIN members m ON m.id = i.member_id JOIN offer_count c ON i.id = c.offer_id
                WHERE school = :school ORDER BY i.id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 6 ";

 foreach ($db->query($sql2, array('school' => $_GET['school'])) AS $result){

<div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                      ";
                      foreach ($db->query($view_photo, array( 'offer_id' => $result['id_count'])) AS $result2){

                          echo "     <img src='profile_pix/{$result2['photo']}' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>";
                      }   echo"      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id={$result['id_count']}' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
}
```

HTML Code:

```
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.danger').attr('', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
        });
        </script>

        <script>
        $(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
        });
        </script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand home_logo" href="index.php">Offcampus<span class="home_logo_small">.com.ng</span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><!-- home_menu-->

                                                         <!--</ul>-->
                <!--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">-->
        <li><a href='login.php?location=%2Fhome.php%3Fschool%3DUniversity%2Bof%2BLagos%26accommodation%3Dsee%2Ball%26price%3Dsee%2Ball%26submit%3DSearch' class=''>Login</a></li>      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Offcampus.com.ng</title>

  </head>
  <body>



    <div class='container'>
    <div class = ''>


    <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-sm-9 '>

                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443351862.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=112' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443351689.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=111' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443351518.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=109' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443351378.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=107' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443351185.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=105' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
                  <div class='user_sec_fav'>                
                    <div class='row'>
                      <div class='col-md-4'>
                           <img src='profile_pix/0_1443350953.jpg' class='img-responsive' width = '300px' height ='' style=' '/>      
                      </div>

                       <div class='col-md-6'>
                        <a href='readmore.php?id=103' class='btn btn-success' style=''>Details</a>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



<div class='col-md-12 text-center'>
<ul class='pagination  pag'><li class='active' ><a href="home.php?school=University of Lagos&accommodation=see all&price=see all&submit=Search&page=1">1</a></li><li><a href="home.php?school=University of Lagos&accommodation=see all&price=see all&submit=Search&page=2">2</a></li></ul></div></div><div class='col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3 con_1'>
      <form class='form-horizontal home_form' role='form' method='get' action='home_2.php'>

          <div class='form-group'>
          <span class='home_text_2'>Your School</span><br class='clear'>
            <select name='school' class='form-control input-3x ' id=''>
                <option value='select' >select....</option>



                <option value='University of Benin'>University of Benin</option>

                <option value='University of Lagos'selected>University of Lagos</option>

                <option value='Yaba College of Technology'>Yaba College of Technology</option>    
            </select>
            </div>

             <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='home_text_2'>Accommodation</span><br class='clear'>
            <select name='accommodation' id='accommodation' class='form-control input-3x'>
                <option value='' >Accommodation Type</option>
                <option value='one room'>One Room</option>
                <option value='one room self-contain' >One Room Self-Contain</option>
                <option value='room and parlor' >Room and Parlour</option>
                <option value='2 bedroom flat'>2 Bedroom Flat</option>
                <option value='3 bedroom flat'>3 Bedroom Flat</option>
                <option value='see all' selected>See All</option>
            </select>
            </div>


            <div class='form-group'>
                <span class='home_text_2'>Budget</span><br class='clear'>
                <select name='price' id='price' class='form-control input-3x'>
                    <option value='' >Price Range.</option>
                    <option value='0-50,000' >0 - 50,000</option>
                    <option value='50,000-100,000' >50,000 - 100,000</option>
                    <option value='100,000-150,000' >100,000 - 150,000</option>
                    <option value='150,000-200,000' >150,000 - 200,000</option>
                    <option value='200,000 and above' >200,000 and above</option>
                    <option value='see all' selected>See All</option>

                </select>

              </div>


          <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='home_text_2'>Exact Location</span><br class='clear'>
            <input type='text' name='location' placeholder='e.g. Dim Gate, Staff Quarters,'  class='home_select_box_2'>
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='home_text_2'>Distance to School</span><br class='clear'>
            <input type='radio' name='distance' value='near' checked>Near
            <input style='' type='radio' name='distance' value='far'>Far
          </div>

          <div class='form-group'>
            <span class='home_text_2'>Water Source</span><br class='clear'>
            <input type='radio' name='water' value='tap'>Borehole
            <input style='margin-left:5px;' type='radio' name='water' value='well'>Well
            <input style='margin-left:5px;' type='radio' name='water' value='both' checked>Both
          </div>  
          <div class='form-group'>  
            <span class='home_text_2'>Distance to a business  centre (Photocopy, Typing, Cybercafe, etc)</span><br class='clear'>
            <input type='radio' name='business' value='near' checked>Near
            <input style='margin-left:5px;' type='radio' name='business' value='far'>Far
          </div>  
          <div class='form-group'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Refine search' class='btn btn-success' style=' '>
          </div>  

          <div class='form-group find_school'>
            Can't find what you looking for? <a href='post_request.php' class=''>Post a Request</a>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>   
</div>
</div>


</body>       
</html>
```

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant in this case. Show your rendered HTML code.

Comment: @makshh html code has been added.

Comment: When you run your page you can view the source in your browser, just copy all HTML and paste it here. You pasted HTML code but there is nothing in the body and we can't help you.

Comment: Nice :) Now I see your problem.

Comment: What is the problem please?

Comment: @makshh I have seen your answer. Please can you tell me how that was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP file change this:

```
<div class='col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10'>
  <div class='user_sec_fav'>
```

To this:

```
<div>
  <div class='user_sec_fav'>
```

Comment: Honestly, you have a little mess in your HTML markup and it is hard to explain what was wrong, but I recommend you to learn about Bootstrap grid and how to nest columns in another columns. (for example you have a div with `col-xs-12` and then div with `col-xs-10` - this is wrong).